# php OOP accessing objects directly

Tags: php, oop

I am learning and trying to understand things concerning oop so my question might sound very silly.

I want to be able to get to an object directly like this:

```
$some_urls = new some_urls;
print_r($some_urls->url()->illegal);
```

Do I have to add the `(object)` before each `array()` inside the function or is there a more efficient way ? Thanks and sorry if it is repeated question, I am looking a long time about this.

```
class some_urls
{
    public function url()
    {
        return (object)array(

            'illegal' => (object)array(
                'a_path',
                'another_path'
            ),

            'legal' => (object)array(
                'a_path',
                'another_path'
            )
        );
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I think I found a better alternative based on some ideas by guys here.
You think this is better ?

```
$some_urls = new some_urls;
print_r($some_urls->get_url('illegal'));


class some_urls
{
public function get_url($data)
{
    $url = $this->url();
    return $url[$data];
}


    protected function url()
    {
        return array(

            'illegal' => array(
                'a_path',
                'another_path'
            ),

            'legal' => array(
                'a_path',
                'another_path'
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Use either class variables or array, easier

Comment: `$some_urls->url()['illegal']` should work in recent PHP versions.

Comment: in version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8 it doesn't :(

Comment: PHP 5.4 supports array dereferencing.

Comment: sure, but doing what I just showed is considered stupid ? does it add another work to be done when it could be done better in php 5.3 ?

Comment: You could write a class `ReturnValue` (or whatever the object returned by `url()` represents) and return an object of that class.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the stdClass

```
$object1 = new stdClass();
$object1->a_path = 'hello';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many options.

Option 1.  Create a standard class, and then add properties as needed

```
$obj = new stdclass();
$obj->illegal=new stdclass();
```

Option 2.  Just work with an array.

Option 3.  Iterate over your array and create an object.

```
foreach($url as $key=>$value){//Build your object}
```

Option 4.  Use json_decode

```
$object = json_decode(json_encode($array), FALSE);
```

Option 5.  Add properties to your class.

```
public variable illegal
```